# How to iterate through nested object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
{
"ret": [],
"retUnderAgt": [],
"sum": {
  "services": [
    {
      "serviceCode": "BET",
      "serviceName": "Bet Games Lottery ",
      "txnTypes": [
        {
          "txnTypeName": "Sale",
          "amount": "0",
          "txnTypeCode": "SALE",
          "amt": "0.0"
        },
        {
          "txnTypeName": "Winning",
          "amount": "0",
          "txnTypeCode": "WIN_CLAIM",
          "amt": "0.0"
        }
      ]
    }]
}
```

}

I am trying to loop over sum like this ----------->>>

```
for(let i in activityDetailedReportData.sum){
  this.finalTotal.push("Total");
  
  for(let j of i.services){
    for(let k of j.txnTypes){
      this.finalTotal.push(k.amount)
    }
  } 
}
```

I am trying to add all amounts in all txnTypes into one array called finalTotal.

I don't know how to loop over txnTypes inside services. Tell me how should I do it?

I've edited the question as needed
Please help me out in this

Comment: please add the object (a small subset) in text form.

Comment: Please also add the result you're currently getting and what you would expect instead

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are trying to do, but if I got your question correctly try this if you want to push all amounts in one 
array

       for(let service in activityDetailedReportData.sum){
             service.forEach(txnTypes => {
                txnTypes.forEach(elem => {
                     this.finalTotal.push(elem.amount)
                })
            })
         }

Comment: @BhuwanPandey there's an error in this : Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'string'

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes atleast a json will be helpful here instead of sccreenshot

meanwhile I could understand, corrected the code
const services = activityDetailedReportData.sum.services;
services.forEach(service => {
        service.txnTypes.forEach(elem => {
             this.finalTotal.push(elem.amount)
        })
    })

Comment: @BhuwanPandey - No reason to replace the OP's `for-of`s with `forEach`es. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder
I personally prefer and suggest to use forEach because of the below reasons

Better Readability
Fewer off-by-one errors
Maintainable as it may be easier to identify what the code is doing
No variable setup

Comment: @BhuwanPandey - All due respect, I have to disagree (fairly strongly) with all of those. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Please check updated code

Comment: @BhuwanPandey Please check updated question

Comment: I also want to push a string called "Total" at the beginning of the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for the outer loop in your code, since you just want to use the single `activityDetailedReportData.sum.services` property:

```
this.finalTotal.push("Total");
for (let j of activityDetailedReportData.sum.services) {
    for (let k of j.txnTypes) {
         this.finalTotal.push(k.amount);
    }
}
```

Live example (using `finalTotal` rather than `this.finalTotal`):

```js
const activityDetailedReportData = {
    "ret": [],
    "retUnderAgt": [],
    "sum": {
      "services": [
        {
          "serviceCode": "BET",
          "serviceName": "Bet Games Lottery ",
          "txnTypes": [
            {
              "txnTypeName": "Sale",
              "amount": "0",
              "txnTypeCode": "SALE",
              "amt": "0.0"
            },
            {
              "txnTypeName": "Winning",
              "amount": "0",
              "txnTypeCode": "WIN_CLAIM",
              "amt": "0.0"
            }
          ]
        }]
    }
};

const finalTotal =[];

finalTotal.push("Total");
  
for (let j of activityDetailedReportData.sum.services) {
    for (let k of j.txnTypes) {
         finalTotal.push(k.amount);
    }
} 

console.log(finalTotal);
```

---

FWIW, that could probably benefit from destructuring:

```
this.finalTotal.push("Total");
for (let {txnTypes} of activityDetailedReportData.sum.services) {
    for (let {amount} of txnTypes) {
         this.finalTotal.push(amount);
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const activityDetailedReportData = {
    "ret": [],
    "retUnderAgt": [],
    "sum": {
      "services": [
        {
          "serviceCode": "BET",
          "serviceName": "Bet Games Lottery ",
          "txnTypes": [
            {
              "txnTypeName": "Sale",
              "amount": "0",
              "txnTypeCode": "SALE",
              "amt": "0.0"
            },
            {
              "txnTypeName": "Winning",
              "amount": "0",
              "txnTypeCode": "WIN_CLAIM",
              "amt": "0.0"
            }
          ]
        }]
    }
};

const finalTotal =[];

finalTotal.push("Total");
for (let {txnTypes} of activityDetailedReportData.sum.services) {
    for (let {amount} of txnTypes) {
         finalTotal.push(amount);
    }
} 

console.log(finalTotal);
```